# String comparison not working as expected!

Tags: vimscript, string-manipulation

So I want to figure out the Operating System and execute a piece of code based on the operating system in my `.vimrc`. However, I'm not able to understand where I'm going wrong.

```
let operating_system = system("awk -F= '/^NAME/{print $2}' /etc/os-release")
echon operating_system
echon operating_system > "CentOS Linux"
echon operating_system < "CentOS Linux"
echon operating_system ==? "CentOS Linux"
echon operating_system ==# "CentOS Linux"
```

This is the output I get when I start vim:

```
"CentOS Linux"
0100
```

Shouldn't `==?` and `==#` evaluate to 1? If not, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not working, because what you have inside `operating_system` variable is a bit more, than just `CentOS Linux`. First of all, those quotes `"` are part of the string. Checkout contents of that file. If you use `=` as a separator, second field actually contains `"` characters (at least that's the case on my system). Also, there probably is some invisible magic character at the end of string - carrige return or new line.

This should work if you change getting the `operating_system` variable to this:

```
let operating_system = join(split(system("sed -n 's/^NAME=\"\\([^\"]\\+\\)\".*$/\\1/p' /etc/os-release")))
```

`sed` will get everything inside `" "` part (I don't know `awk` that well to do this with it), and the `join`/`split` combo will remove those invisible characters.

Answer (score 2):

Note that you don't need to execute external processes with `system()` which adds trailing newlines & all.

```
let os = matchstr(filter(readfile('/etc/os-release'), 'v:val =~ "^NAME"')[0], '.*"\zs.*\ze".*')
```

with:

- [`readfile()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#readfile%28%29) to read the system file
- [`filter()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#filter%28%29) to keep only the line with `NAME=`
- [`matchstr()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#matchstr%28%29) with extract the content of the *name* field (in the first line `[0]`)

BTW, `/etc/redhat-release` also has the information you're looking for.

```
let is_centos = readfile('/etc/redhat-release')[0] =~ 'CentOS Linux'
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply! Your method works too! About parsing the `/etc/redhat-release` file, I think I'll be sticking to `/etc/os-release` would be better since its a generalized solution and if it is some other OS I'm working on, I can customize based on the output.